# we are integrating .net application with salesforce getting this error

Tags: ssl, salesforce, ssl-certificate, integration

Error when calling the web service of the .Net application from salesforce :

> Creation of Property Failed Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: An error occurred when verifying security for the message. faultcode=a:InvalidSecurity faultactor=

Comment: Put more details in your question. Add some code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check [Integrating Force.com with Microsoft .NET](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET) or [How to Connect Salesforce API With C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kbpatel/integrating-salesforce-with-microsoft-net-C-Sharp/)